# My .exe opens and closes on other computers

Tags: c#, exe

I made a fifa15 trainer script, but I'm having trouble sending it to other people, to debug it I asked another user to run the .exe and send me the logs, but he said the program just opens and closes. Could this be a compatibility issue?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace cheat_birthyear
{
class Program
{
    public static string path;
    public static IntPtr BaseAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("fifa15");
        if(processes.Length > 0)
        {
            IntPtr BaseAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
            Process MyProc = processes[0];
            foreach(ProcessModule module in MyProc.Modules)
            {
                if (module.ModuleName.Contains("fifa15"))
                {
                    BaseAddress = module.BaseAddress;
                    path = module.FileName;
                    Console.WriteLine(path);

                }
            }

            if (BaseAddress != IntPtr.Zero)
            {


                VAMemory memory = new VAMemory("fifa15");
                long finalAddress = memory.ReadInt64((IntPtr)BaseAddress + 0x01F441E8);
                Console.WriteLine(finalAddress);
                int newaddr = memory.ReadInt32( (IntPtr)finalAddress + 0x390);
                Console.WriteLine(newaddr);
                Console.ReadLine();
                string yearPath = path.Replace("fifa15.exe", "cheat_birthyear\\birthyear.txt");
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@yearPath);
                string yearVal = lines[0];
                //float Basefifthvalue = memory.ReadFloat((IntPtr)newaddr);
                //Console.WriteLine(Basefifthvalue);

                memory.WriteInt32((IntPtr)finalAddress + 0x390, 1998);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("baseaddress não encontrado");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("jogo não encontrado");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
 }
```

And these are the generator files when I compile and generate a publish version

[Print of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L71g6.png)

Is there any way to debug so I know if the program was run correctly on another computer?

Comment: A few things 1) If the same version of net is not on machine then you need to publish application.  2) So window does close you can open a cmd.exe.  Then run application with >cmd -k "exe filename" (not quotes).  The cmd window will stay open so you can read any console messages.

Comment: Addition to @jdweng's comment, you can use log errors to a file (e.g log4net) so your friend can send you the log file.

Comment: It might also be helpful to view, on the computer where the issue occurs, the Windows Event Viewer. Search for "Event Viewer" from the Start Menu, then check "Windows Logs" -> "Application". Sometimes if a file is missing it'll be reported as an error here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 paths your application can take

1. There are no Fifa15 processes
2. The BaseAddress is IntPtr.Zero
3. The BaseAddress is not IntPtr.Zero (the app works)
4. Something blows up

In cases one and two you added a `Console.ReadLine()` call which will keep the console open after your code is finished. It appears you forgot this in #3 and #4.

Perhaps try restructuring the code to always call `Console.ReadLine()` so the console stays open and they can see the results. Possibly something like this:

```cs
using System;
//... the rest of the imports

namespace cheat_birthyear
{
    class Program
    {
        //... other class code

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try {
                //... your code here
            } finally {
                Console.ReadLine()
            }
        }
    }
}
```